# image src is not set on my code in side a condition when it's true but it's done outside of it

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get an explaination about whats happen exactly with this code , I see that everything is working and the other part are working as expected , but inside the condition when reaching the index 2 is not giving the image the src, when I checked the console I saw that the img.src is get the value correctly but it does not pass it to the node

```
var img = document.createElement('img');

                  let randIndex;
                  if (usedImages.length < gameData.length) {
                      do {
                          randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameData.length);
                      } while (usedImages.includes(randIndex));
                      usedImages.push(randIndex);
                      img.src = gameData[randIndex].url;
                      img.id = 'card-i-' + gameData[randIndex].key;
                      imageIds.push('card-i-' + gameData[randIndex].key);
                  } else {
                      [0,1,2].forEach(index=>{
                          if (usedImages.filter(value => value === index).length < 2) {
                              img.src = gameData[index].url;
                              console.log('here created',gameData[index].url)
                              usedImages.push(index);
                              img.id = 'card-i-' + gameData[index].key;
                              imageIds.push('card-i-' + gameData[index].key);
                          }
                      })
                  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at this quickly.

```
usedImages.filter(value => value === index).length < 2
```

That's stating if less than 2 when the index is 3. So it's not running the last image number two (which is the 3rd in the array). Should be ...

```
usedImages.filter(value => value === index).length < 3
```

Comment: it's true , I thinl because of a lot of focus I missed it  but following the logic it should be 4 to display all images, I mean I added 4 cases and check with 4, thanks bro.